# Create an Image either using Magick Wand or ImageMagick on Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, imagemagick, magickwand, pythonmagick

There's not enough information on Internet about imagemagick and magick wand on Python 3. I need to create a lot of images using Python 3, creating the images with a background color or a background image.

When I get the image with the background I want, then I need to add text with a font of my preference on It, I think I can solve the problem of the font, but how to add the "string" in the image?

After that, I want to save the image with a "name". 
I have installed Magick wand and Image Magick on Python 3, but the documentation is in a language that I really don't understand. Do I need to install something else?
If you're able to help me, it would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve these using [Wand](http://wand-py.org/).

- [Creating the images with a background color](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.3-maintenance/guide/read.html#open-an-empty-image) or a [background image](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.3-maintenance/guide/read.html#open-image-file)
- [Add text with a font](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.3-maintenance/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.caption)
- [Save the image with a “name”](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.3-maintenance/guide/write.html#save-to-file)